# How would you call a speed camera in Taiwan

Tags: translation, taiwan

a speed camera, that takes a picture of you (and your license plate) if you drive too fast.

My dictionary calls this a

> 電子警察

But I´m pretty sure noone in Taiwan (or even Mainland) will call a speed camera like this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it’s called “測速照相機”, or “測速相機”

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about what this will be called in Taiwan, but in mainland, this is called "测速仪" or "电子测速仪".